# How to redirect to a custom 404 page in remix.run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, remix.run

I am trying to redirect the URL to a custom 404 page in remix.run but not able to do so. I have a url structure something like this -

```
app/
 ├── routes/
 │   ├── $dynamicfolder/
 │   │   ├── index.tsx
 │   │   ├── somepage.tsx
 │   │   ├── $.tsx
 │   └── index.tsx
 └── root.tsx
```

I have a certain number of pages under `$dynamicfolder` and they are accessible like this -

```
"https://example.com/xx/" (This is to access the index.tsx, I have 2 fixed values that are 
passed in "$dynamicfolder", let's say xx and xy),


"https://example.com/xx/somepage" (This is to access the other page)
```

When some other random value is passed in `$dynamicfolder`, let's say "**yy**", like this -

```
"https://example.com/yy/"
```

then I want that to be handled by `$.tsx` which is also inside `$dynamicfolder`. Unfortunately, that's not happening and it is throwing an obvious error.

I am accessing the value of `$dynamicfolder` in `$dynamicfolder/index.tsx` using `useParams()` hook. I just want to redirect the page to 404 when any other value apart from `xx` and `xy` is passed.

I did follow the remix docs, [Splat URLs](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#splat-routes) and [Dynamic routes parameters](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#dynamic-route-parameters) but maybe I am doing some kind of mistake that I am not able to catch.

It is also possible that I might be doing it in the wrong way as I am new to remix.run. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loader, check the params and `throw new Response('Not found', 404)` as needed. Throwing a response will render the closest `<CatchBoundary>`

In your *root* route, export a `<CatchBoundary>` to display your custom 404 error.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/not-found#root-catch-boundary

Comment: My requirement was not exactly this, but pretty much similar. This answer gave me an idea to solve my problem. Thanks :)